# Fastest way to zero

Tags: c, zero, 8051, unsigned-integer

What is the fastest way to zero out an unsigned int?

I am currently just setting the value to 0, but I don't know if there are any tricks for zeroing out a variable? I need a few clock cycles back in my current project. I am using a standard 8051 processor and I have two different variables I need to get to zero if that helps at all.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any better opportunities to optimize?

Comment: Setting it to `0` should already be fast. Are you really losing performance to variable assignments? Seems very microscale.

Comment: Not in my current Interrupt. It is interrupting every 10 [us]. Wish I had the foresight to choose a faster processor in the beginning but I am committed to the one I'm currently using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is labelled 8051, so if the need is to zero out a register XORing the register with itself will be a faster way to zero it out, instead of moving a zero in it. One opcode fetch and decode vs opcode fetch decode and operand fetch.

If you are using higher level language and not hand assembling or writing in asm, then it is better to use `var = 0`. The compiler will take care of the required optimizations.

Comment: Thanks. I think XORing might be able to give me the few cycles I need. Appreciate the suggestion

Comment: Self-XOR is about as fast as it gets. I'm puzzled though, unless you are programming directly in assembler virtually any compiler will initialize variables the same way.

Comment: but if you are using high level language to write code, then i think it is better to leave it to the compiler to optimize.

Comment: A good compiler will use self-xor to implement zero-assignment if that's the optimal way to do it on the target machine. GCC even does this on x86, at least with `-Os`...

Answer (score 3):

Write your code for humans, don't waste any effort optimizing things that don't need to be optimized. When you want to assign zero to variable, then assign zero to variable: `x = 0;`

**It's easier to make a correct program fast than it's to make a fast program correct.**

Comment: I will definitely take that advice, but this project is specifically about optimizing what currently exists. This code should not have to ever be seen by another human though except myself.

Comment: @JoeWanja is dealing with hardware registers. Having written a boot rom console and an NT device driver, I can say from experience that the code isn't for humans. It's for whatever works.

Comment: Yes, I see. [tag:c] tag confused me.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the compiler will optimize this sort of thing for you. Remember that micro-optimizations lead to micro-results.

Answer (score 1):

Micro-optimizations lead to micro-results.

You can likely xor a variable with itself to achieve zero. Chances are great your compiler is already doing it that way, if not something faster.

Answer (score 0):

First try to implement a way of timing a block of code containing the code in question, if you have not already done that.

Then, try var = 0; and use the compiler switch that generates assembler in the listing. Then do the same thing for the XOR solution. It represents a bit of extra work, but then you'll have the results right there.